# Dropdown filter doesn't work in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, dropdown

I tried to do the input dropdown filter using this code:

```
<div class="col-md-2">  
    <div class="text-justify" >
        <select class="itemName form-control form-filter" style="width:90px;" name="itemName" id="itemName">
            @foreach($data as $category){
                 <option value="{{$category->Umur}}">{{$category->Umur}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, my code does not run as I expected (in picture below) - the code only call the first row in database. What should I edit with the code?

[image: Error]

Comment: can you post the controller part for `$data`?

Comment: class FiltersController extends Controller
{
    public function filter(){
        $data = create::all();
        return view('pages.custom', ['data' => $data]);
    }
}

Comment: this is the controller

Comment: is `create` a model??

Comment: <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\ModifiedDppr;

class FiltersController extends Controller
{
    public function filter(){
        $data = ModifiedDppr::all();
        return view('pages.custom', ['data' => $data]);
    }
}
  ..ModifiedDppr is the model

Comment: I've changed the controller (ModifiedDppr as model)

Comment: @CcSee Can you try `dd($data)` in the controller?

Comment: @CcSee Put your model code also in the question

Comment: are you using `select2`??

Comment: yes - forgot to mention that. Solved.Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-2">  
    <div class="text-justify" >
        <select class="itemName form-control form-filter" style="width:90px;" name="itemName" id="itemName">
            @foreach($data as $category){
                 <option value="{{$category->Umur}}">{{$category->Umur}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

remove the {  after @foreach & change the value like

```
<div class="col-md-2">  
    <div class="text-justify" >
        <select class="itemName form-control form-filter" style="width:90px;" name="itemName" id="itemName">
            @foreach($data as $category)
                 <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->Umur}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It still call only the first row of database table

Comment: I removed the itemName in class. However, the input box is missing. I only can use the dropdown. How I can fix it? (already try lot of ways-failed)

Comment: what is the result when you dd($data)

Comment: Solved.Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I too had this issue myself, this is what i used:

```
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                          <input list="brow" class="form-control"name="instagram_account_id" id="instagram_account_id" placeholder="Search..">
                                <datalist id="brow">
                                    @if($users->count() > 0)
                                      @foreach($users as $user)    
                         <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{ $user->username }}</option>
                                      @endforeach 
                                    @else 
                                    No User(s) Found
                                    @endif
                                </datalist>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

As for my controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $comments = Comment::paginate(10);
        $users = InstagramAccount::all();


        return view('instagramComments', [
            'comments' => $comments,
            'users' => $users,
        ]);
    }
```

And (if you're going to use it an a form) my insert in my controller:

```
public function insert(Request $req)
    {
        $instagram_comment = $req->input('instagram_comment');
        $instagram_account_id = $req->input('instagram_account_id');

        $data = array('comment'=>$instagram_comment, 'account_id'=>$instagram_account_id);

        DB::table('comments')->insert($data);
        return redirect('/comments');
    }
```

(if using the insert above, use this in your web route):

```
Route::post('/locationsInsert', 'InstagramLocationsController@insert')->middleware('auth');
```

Hope any of this helps!

Comment: Solved.Thanks for your help!